# Azure Service Fabric how to size Actors and networks

Tags: azure, actor, partitioning, azure-service-fabric

What methodologies should be applied in determining correct actor size for an azure service fabric stateful actor system?

Taken to the extremes I could have *theoretically* have exactly 1 actor that has **all the state** or the converse use an actor to store exactly 1 string. Obviously both of these are wrong.

For a single actor, if measuring the serialized size of the data what amounts of **kilo**bytes would be considered small and how many **mega**bytes would be considered large? For example, is 10KB small and 10MB large?

Building from the above answer, assuming an actor network compromised of "small" actors. What constitutes a small network vs a large network? For example again, is 1 million small and 1 billion large?

I'd strongly prefer some kind of citation applied to these measurements. However I have not been able to source anything specific from the Azure docs. Should no specific information be published yet, I would accept sources that deal with different actor network implementations than specifically the ASF.

Comment: What “correct size” does mean in this context? Real size of an actor in kilobytes?

Comment: @cassandrad in regards to a single actor `For example, is 10KB small and 10MB large?` and in regards to the network as whole `For example again, is 1 million small and 1 billion large?`

Comment: Looks like you are asking about “best practices” on data amount to store in an actor and it is very broad to give some particular answer. Why can't you measure using of many actors with different amount of data stored in your environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the raw size of the actor's state is less interesting than its scope and patterns of access. If you're using your actor as a "manager" of a large amount of state that other components need to access various pieces of, you are very likely to get tripped up by the single-threaded nature of the actor model as multiple callers attempt to make requests in parallel. On the other hand, if you have a naturally encapsulated actor that needs to harness a large amount of state to perform its tasks, it can be beneficial to have all of that state stored locally, rather than making a set of network requests.

If you're looking for a very coarse rule of thumb, I would expect most actor state to be measured in kilobytes. If you're crossing the megabyte threshold, it's worth re-examining your design and making sure your actors aren't playing the manager or mini-database role, which would be much better served with a reliable service/reliable dictionary.

Comment: You affirmed my assumptions about the serialized data size, that kilobytes (persisted) is the sweet spot. What about the number of actors in a system? Maybe assume 5KB to 25KB per actor (pretty contiguous blocks of data that would be updated in a single transaction boundary)

Comment: Actor services are partitioned so there's no such sweet spot for their number. If the number of actors you have runs up against the limits of your hardware, you can simply add more machines to the cluster and Service Fabric will rebalance.

Comment: Let me rephrase, how do you handle capacity planning aka what metrics can be applied to say "at this point is when we should expect to increase the servers" (increase them above the standard triplet set of servers). As opposed to reactionary the cluster is overloaded / out of capacity and we must upgrade now now now. I always to try plan to eliminate the now now now responses.

Comment: There isn't a significant amount of overhead platform state so the capacity planning exercise is basically: custom actor state size * number of actors * number of replicas. You can see an example [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-capacity-planning/).